# how to echo before running a command, shell script

Tags: linux

i am making a shell script that will echo my name, and then echo "the date today is" and run date. but when it runs date it erases "the date today is"
ive also tried not having the pipe, and having the date command on the next line. but both of those do not work the way i am looking for.

```
#Michael LaPan
#3/19/2014
clear
echo Michael LaPan
echo "the date today is:" | date
```

right now it just looks like

```
Michael LaPan
Wed Mar 19 19:40:53 EDT 2014
```

how i want it to look

```
Michael LaPan
 the date today is: Wed Mar 19 19:40:53 EDT 2014
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is shell command expansion operator or `$()`.

Try:

```
echo "the date today is: `date`"
```

or

```
echo "the date today is: $(date)"
```

Comment: This is pointless extra work.  This makes the shell keep track of the output of date and write it to its output, generating needless I/O. It is much cleaner to simply write the date to the correct place in the first place.

Comment: echo "the date today is: `date`" this outputs the date today is: 'date'

Comment: note that backtics are deprecated in bash (that's why I've edited the post) I guess also POSIX requires `$()` (but I'm not and too lazy to search)

Comment: Don't worry, the shell doesn't mind doing all of that extra work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo -n "the date today is:" ; date
```

By piping the output of echo to date, you are effectively discarding it, since date ignores it.  By running them serially, the output of both echo and date go to the output of the script.  Use `-n` to suppress the newline that would otherwise appear.

Comment: @hek2mgl, because I can't spell `-n`!

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
echo "The date today is: " `date`
```

This should work all the way back to 7th Edition Unix. I never laid my hands on anything earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to get date which you want

echo -n "the date today is:"; date